# Excel Script that Compares a columns data and highlights a difference

Tags: excel, scripting, vba

I am trying to compare to worksheets that share the same information but show a before (worksheet 1) and after (worksheet 2). So, I want to highlight (print or format) the cells that are different than the before. I need to compare the values in Column C and D based on the columns in A and B. So if SiteID 1 SiteName a has a different Level 1 OR Level 2 in Worksheet 2 I need to identify that somehow. Any help is much appreciated.

Example:
http://imgur.com/h1olLlB

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of what you are trying to do, but I'm thinking you'll need a vlookup with some nested if statements?! If the rows are in the same order you could get away without using vlookup.

My over-all recommendation for this kind of comparison is using a database as it gives you more robust functionality without getting into VBA or lengthy formulas.

Sample data as well as a sample of what you want the output to be will help write the actual code you need.

Comment: It wont let me upload a picture because I do not have a 10 reputation. I am new to Stackoverflow so I am still trying to figure it all out. I have a screenshot of an example that will help clarify what I am trying to do.